# Dialog box in Material UI opens with a weird gray background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

Im using Material UI with React and have a dialog which comes up when a button is tapped. The button is present in a table which in turn is presented over a Paper component.
The issue is when I use the dialog with default styling, the background turns black. I tried making the styling as transparent but now Im getting a gray artifact behind dialog.
The original dialog with default styling:

[image: Dialog with default styling]

The dialog with transparent attributes:

```
    <Dialog
      title="ALERT - Confirm Action? "
      modal={false}
      overlayStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
      bodyStyle={{margin:0, padding:0}}
      actions={
        <div>
          <FlatButton
              label="Cancel"
              primary={true}
              onClick={this.handleCloseTwo}
          />
          <FlatButton
              label="Submit"
              type="submit"
              primary={true}
              keyboardFocused={true}
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ dialogTwo: false });
              }}
          />
        </div>
      }
      open={this.state.dialogTwo}
  >
  </Dialog>
```

This is how it renders:
[image]

Comment: Weird. You need to inspect the css and see from where the effects are coming. Some other css might be messing things up.

Comment: if you can add any plunker or jsfiddle, it will help us in finding the issue..

Comment: It looks like many dialogs opened at the same time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the solution now. Your dialog code (

> **`<Dialog> </Dialog>`**

), put them outside the component you use.

example:

```js
<Table>
....
<IconButton> Dialog Show </IconButton>
<Dialog> .............. </Dialog>
....
</Table>
```

put them like this

```js
<Table>
....
<IconButton> Dialog Show </IconButton>
....
</Table>

<Dialog> .............. </Dialog>
```

Comment: amazing serves the purpose, but why?

Answer (score 4):

If anybody still stumble upon this, and do not notice the the answer from Mikhail Shabrikov in the comments, because its not posted as an answer:

> It looks like many dialogs opened at the same time. – Mikhail Shabrikov Oct 26 '17 at 9:07

I have been back to this page at least the 3. time in the last year, thus adding this answer because I keep missing this (and keep putting my dialogs in iterators) :).

Answer (score 0):

My dialog box is worse than your code. I added code to the array loop so this dialog is blinking and the background color is black because of the array loop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33842021)